# Fresh Ubuntu 12.10 - no audio (Thinkpad T400)

Tags: 12.10, sound, thinkpad

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Thinkpad T400 ... but I have no sound and the keyboard buttons for volume up and down do nothing. When I open sound settings, there's nothing: it's all greyed out. It is like the driver is missing.

Alsamixer gives :

```
card :HDA Intel                              
chip: Conexant CX20561 (Hermosa)
```

What can I do?

T400:~$ sudo aplay -l

```
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels PLAYBACK ****
Home directory /home/louisro not ours.
carte 0: Intel [HDA Intel], périphérique 0: CONEXANT Analog [CONEXANT Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: Intel [HDA Intel], périphérique 1: Conexant Digital [Conexant Digital]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

T400:~$ lspci -v | grep -iA 7 'audio'

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f2
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
Memory at fc020000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

[image]

In the upper bar the sound icon is not functionning:
[image]

The sound works out of the box with a live USB ubuntu with /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf containing the following:

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

Comment: post the output of `sudo aplay -l`. Please post also the output of: `lspci -v | grep -iA 7 'audio'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My /home is mounted from a separate partition, and this partition was ntfs, so there was permissions problems...Now I formatted this partition to ext4....and the sound works!

Answer (score 1):

Driver is ok.

Open alsamixer, make sure your output channels are not muted. Press the left and right arrow keys, to move to different channels and press m to toggle mute / unmute. A "M/M" at the bottom of a column means it's muted

It should look kinda like this:

[image: alsamixer screenshot]

Comment: thanks but I checked and they were not muted...still no sound

Comment: try: `/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 sset "Auto-Mute Mode" Disabled`

Comment: run: `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add this line `options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad`. You will have to reboot. If that doesn't help try resetting your BIOS to factory defaults.

Comment: I did the auto-mute command and added the line in the alas-base.conf file, still no sound ! I also reset the bios to factory settings ...still nothing, any other ideas?

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm stumbling in the dark. Please try changing the  line in the conf file to `option snd-hda-intel model=generic`, reboot.

Comment: or possibly: `option snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad power_save=0 power_save_controller=N`. But it feels like a hardware failure.

Comment: I guees that you meant "options" instead of "option"....I tried those but still the same....

Comment: I is not hardware failure because it works out of the box with a live USB ubuntu.

Comment: Try reinstalling everything alsa related libasound alsa-oss etc, or [upgrading alsa](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS). I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: I just reinstalled everything alsa related...no I have sound, but I stille can't control it (the icon is not functional in the upper right corner)

Comment: you have sound now? That's awesome. Try: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-sound`, then `killall unity-panel-service`. Do your sound control keys work? You might have to restart pulseaudio: `pulseaudio -k`

Comment: yes I have sound now . But I have strange errors on $ pulseaudio -k
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory: Permission not granted
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Impossible to kill the daemon  : Permission not granted

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio`

Comment: Hi....my /home was mounted from a separate partition, and this partition was ntfs, so there was permissions problems...Now I formatted this partition to ext4....and the sound works!