# Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series isn't being detected by any module

Tags: kernel

I have the same problem that the user in "Dummy Output in Ubuntu 14.04".

The difference is that cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec outputs:

```
cat: /proc/asound/card0/codec*: No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

(It's in Spanish, it means it cannot find the file or directory)

More info:

```
$ sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel  
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-intel not found.

$ sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).

$ sudo aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found... 

$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
    High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

$ lspci -v | grep audio
(nothing)

$ locate snd-hda-intel
(nothing)

$ lsmod | grep snd
(nothing)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo lspci -nnk | grep -A5 Audio`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we need to know what type of audio hardware (if any) the system detects:

```
lspci -v | grep audio
```

And

```
:~$ lsmod | grep snd
```

Please run this command and post the output. Should be something like the following:

```
:~$ lspci -v | grep audio
00:1f.4 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801BA/BAM AC'97 \
  Audio     Controller (rev 02)
:~$
```

And

```
snd_intel8x0           38153  0
snd_ac97_codec        130285  1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus               12730  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm               102099  2 snd_ac97_codec,snd_intel8x0
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
snd_timer              29482  1 snd_pcm
snd                    69238  4 snd_ac97_codec,snd_intel8x0,snd_timer,snd_pcm
soundcore              12680  1 snd
:~$
```

### Additional information for troubleshooting

What is the output of the following?

```
:~$ locate snd-hda-intel
```

Several users on other posts were able to get this audio chipset working by editing */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*

```
nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

And add the following line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

Posts referenced/researched:

- [Fresh Ubuntu 12.10 - no audio (Thinkpad T400)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257521/fresh-ubuntu-12-10-no-audio-thinkpad-t400)
- [Driver for Intel
  Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=103547)

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering. I tried all the commands you posted and I got no output.  I also tried adding the line in alsa-base (and rebooting) but it didn't work.

Comment: @marlan21 - I added an additional solution and posted it as a separate answer. Here we take the approach that some packages may be mis/unconfigured.

Answer (score 2):

Several users on other posts were able to get this audio chipset working by editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

And add the following line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

This worked for me on a Philips Freevent x55, although I had to use `sudo gedit` instead of nano.

Comment: `sudo nano` would also work--the key is that files in `/etc/modprobe.d` must be created/edited as root. Btw, you should use `sudo -H gedit` or `sudo -i gedit` (or `gksudo gedit` if the gksu package is installed) instead of `sudo gedit`. [Running graphical programs like gedit with plain sudo sometimes causes hassles later by causing there to be root-owned dotfiles in the non-root user's home directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application).

Comment: worked, had problem after upgrading several LTS releases of ubuntu (currently on 22.04)

Answer (score 0):

### Alternate method to fix sound (due to misconfigured/unconfigured packages after install/update/upgrade).

- Fix packages that are not properly configured

`:~$sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then do a
`:~$sudo reboot`

Post referenced: [It's F.O.S.S., Fix No Sound in Ubuntu](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)

Comment: It didn't work either. Mmm I not exactly sure how this happened, I tried to update alsa installing the driver found in the realtek website. Perhaps it's better to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch don't you think?

Comment: @marlan21, maybe that is the easiest option. But, why are you installing realtek drivers for an Intel chipset?

Comment: I wanted to split the sound of the front connectors with the ones in the back. I read in a website that this was the way to do it, but I guess it was wrong.